# Having trouble to connect to (remote) MySQL database with MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using a Mac with macOS 10.11.6. I want to connect MySQLWorkbench 6.3.7 to a MySQL database stored on my Linux server. I'm able to create a connection with Sequel Pro but it doesn't work doing the same in MySQLWorkbench. This is what I am doing:

```
1. Open "Setup New Connection" window
2. Selecting "Standard TCP/IP over SSH"
3. SSH Hostname = my servers IP
4. SSH Username = same I use to login in MySQL database with PHPMyAdmin
5. SSH Password = same I use to login in MySQL database with PHPMyAdmin
6. SSH Key File = I do nothing here, stays empty
7. MySQL Hostname = my servers IP
8. MySQL Server Port = I do nothing here, stays empty
9. Username = same I use to login in MySQL database with PHPMyAdmin
10. Password = this is the password I also use to access my server with the FTP client
11. Default Schema = I do nothing here, stays empty
```

When clicking "Test Connection", I get:

```
Please enter password for the following service:
Service: Mysql@MY_IP:3306@MY_IP
User: MY_USERNAME
```

When I enter the password I get:

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at MY_IP:3306 through SSH tunnel at MY_USERNAME@MY_IP with user MY_USERNAME
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody help me please?

P.S. I replaced the IP and the username with MY_IP and MY_USERNAME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your remote server has ssh enabled on it.

Second, assuming it does have SSH enabled on it, *usually* the SSH username and the MySQL username will be different (for security reasons). Regardless, make sure you have the correct SSH username / password (and it sounds like you already have the correct MySQL username / password).

Third:

```
4. SSH Username = same I use to login in MySQL database with PHPMyAdmin
   - See above
5. SSH Password = same I use to login in MySQL database with PHPMyAdmin
   - See above
7. MySQL Hostname = my servers IP
   - Usually the value for this is either localhost or 127.0.0.1 - try either of
     those and see what happens.
```

On a personal note, I tried upgrading my version of MySQL Workbench (using OSX) and I had nothing but problems so I had to download a previous version. The only one that seems to work for me is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.39-osx-i686.dmg). If none of the suggestions I made above work for you, maybe try removing your current version and downloading an earlier version just to see if that's what's causing the problem or not.

Comment: Hi, it worked with `localhost` as `MySQL Hostname`. But still a problem. I've three databases. All are shown in the left side bar. But the tables aren't shown up. I get: `Tables could not be fetched`. In the action output window I get: `11:13:09 Error loading schema content Error Code: 1558 Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. Created with MySQL 50051, now running 50173. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.` What will happen when I use `mysql_upgrade`? I don't want do destroy something. And, how to use it?

Comment: @David that's really a whole different question in and of itself... Would be much better to just post a new question or do a little research, but either way be sure to back everything up if you're able to (before doing the upgrade).